# Calling a function with a vector doesn't work for me

Tags: functions, vector

I'm trying to create a simple function that generates a transformation matrix from the partial derivatives of two coordinate systems.  It currently works when I have it written like this:

```
x[r_, theta_] = r*Cos[theta]; 
y[r_, theta_] = r*Sin[theta]; 

transformationMatrix[r_, theta_] = 
   {{D[x[r, theta], r], D[x[r, theta], theta]}, 
    {D[y[r, theta], r], D[y[r, theta], theta]}}; 

In[123]:= transformationMatrix[0.3, 0.5]    
Out[123]= {{0.877583, -0.143828}, {0.479426, 0.263275}}
```

But I want the function to work with vectors, not scalars, so I change it to this:

```
x[xPrime_] = xPrime[[1]]*Cos[xPrime[[2]]]; 
y[xPrime_] = xPrime[[1]]*Sin[xPrime[[2]]]; 

transformationMatrix[xPrime_] = 
   {{D[x[xPrime], xPrime[[1]]], D[x[xPrime], xPrime[[2]]]}, 
    {D[y[xPrime], xPrime[[1]]], D[y[xPrime], xPrime[[2]]]}}; 

transformationMatrix[{0.3, 0.5}]
```

and I get a bunch of errors that say:

```
Part::partd: Part specification xPrime[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
Part::partd: Part specification xPrime[[2]] is longer than depth of object. >>
Part::partd: Part specification xPrime[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
Part::partd: Part specification xPrime[[2]] is longer than depth of object. >>
```

Fine, so I'll try deferring the evaluation with this:

```
x[xPrime_] := xPrime[[1]]*Cos[xPrime[[2]]]; 
y[xPrime_] := xPrime[[1]]*Sin[xPrime[[2]]]; 
transformationMatrix[xPrime_] := 
   {{D[x[xPrime], xPrime[[1]]], D[x[xPrime], xPrime[[2]]]}, 
    {D[y[xPrime], xPrime[[1]]], D[y[xPrime], xPrime[[2]]]}}; 
transformationMatrix[{0.3, 0.5}]
```

And I get this:

```
General::ivar: 0.3` is not a valid variable. >>
General::ivar: 0.5` is not a valid variable. >>
General::ivar: 0.3` is not a valid variable. >>
```

I need some help.  How should I be constructing this function to work with vectors?  Is there a more natural way in Mathematica to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a 2nd definition for `transformationMatrix`

```
x[r_, theta_] := r*Cos[theta]
y[r_, theta_] := r*Sin[theta]

transformationMatrix[r_, theta_] = 
  {{D[x[r, theta], r], D[x[r, theta], theta]}, 
   {D[y[r, theta], r], D[y[r, theta], theta]}};

transformationMatrix[{r_, theta_}] := transformationMatrix[r, theta]
```

Then

```
transformationMatrix[{0.3, 0.5}]
```

gives the same answer as

```
transformationMatrix[0.3, 0.5]
```

Note: `transformationMatrix[Sequence @@ {0.3, 0.5}]` will give the results you want with your original code.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the function that the parameters are a sequence?  Similar to what you did with the caller there.

Comment: @Quarkly. The parameters of are always  a sequence; you don't have to tell a function that they are. That's why `Sequence @@ {0.3, 0.5}` works.

Comment: The function **x[vector_] = vector[[1]]*Cos[vector[[2]]]** most definitely needs to be told that **vector** is an array, otherwise it spits out those messages "Part specification vector[[1]] is longer than depth of object.".

Comment: @Quarkly, use `:=`, as in `x[vector_] := vector[[1]]*Cos[vector[[2]]]`. That way it won't try to do anything until it knows what `vector` is.